# VNext Build 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, tfs-2015, vnext

Iam trying to build the solution of C# using the TFS 2015 through visual studio build step. In the solution i  want to exclude a Specific folder so it will not be picked during the solution building.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNkNK.png)

I can exclude the folder explicitly through right click on the folder(Tests) and can select Remove projects in solution fodler in Visual studio, but want to know how to do through Vnext Build using Visual studio Build step.

Answer (score 0):

If a project is part of a solution and it's set to build for a given platform/configuration combination, of course it's going to build if you attempt to build that platform/configuration.

Modify your solution to [exclude building the project(s)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the platform/configuration you're building. There is no other option; MSBuild doesn't have support for excluding certain projects, so you can't specify additional MSBuild parameters to prevent it from building certain projects.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for your help.
It help me to get what is requried.